# How to get reciprocal (1/x) in scientific mode in Windows 10 calculator

Tags: windows-10, calculator

I'm sure there's an obvious answer to this...

In Windows 10 calculator, the standard mode has a reciprocal (1/x) button, but scientific mode does not. However, it's not possible to switch back to standard mode to perform a reciprocal operation because this clears the current value.

I realize I could use the memory, but surely there is an easier way?

Comment: Strange, I can see `1/x` button in both modes.

Comment: @PetSerAl that's because your window is big. Try resizing the calculator to make it smaller and then it'll automatically rearrange the buttons

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Windows 10 calculator changes slightly depending on the size of the window.  You've probably got it a little bit on the small side, so, in order to access the reciprocal button, you need to use the shift button:

[image: Windows 10 Calculator]

You'll notice when you click the shift button, you'll see a new set of functions.  Alternatively, you can just make the window taller and they will all appear.

Comment: Thanks I never noticed the shift button - on my PC it's the same color as all the others. I couldn't get all the buttons to show by making it taller (maybe my monitor isn't high enough) but I could by making it wider. I've no idea why they made the buttons so big though - the window has to nearly fill the screen before all the buttons appear.

Comment: @Andy yes I agree the behavior is pretty unintuitive, and my button is only colored differently because I took the screenshot with the button pressed, it is usually black as well making it very difficult to find.

Comment: Wow, this is very poor UI design. Unbelievable, coming from Microsoft. I just went full screen with the calculator and saw tons of new buttons.

Comment: @Andy I suspect the buttons are this big because all the new Windows 10 UI is intended to be touch-friendly (with no exceptions made for devices that don't even have a touchscreen).

Answer (score 7):

#### The standard mode has a reciprocal (1/x) button, but scientific mode does not

The Windows 10 calculator has some shortcuts you can use.

One of them is:

> <kbd>R</kbd> - Select 1/x (Reciprocal).

Source [Useful Calculator keyboard shortcuts in Windows 10](http://winaero.com/blog/useful-calculator-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-10/)